# Child navigation in scoped region

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism, region

I have a `MyTabView` and a `MyTabViewModel`, the view injected into a tab region and `MyTabView` have their own `RegionManager` (scoped region manager). This `MyTabView` have a region on it (call it "mycontentregion"), where I want to inject another view by default, when `MyTabView` is injected to a tab region. See picture below for clarification.

[image]

I want to inject a View into mycontentregion right after it injected to tab region.
Simple navigation with a button on MyTabView with the following command works fine.

```
RegionManager.RequestNavigate("mycontentregion", nameof(AnotherView));
```

I can't put this navigation request to `OnNavigatedTo` method in `MyTabView` because it became in infinite loop. Interestingly `OnNavigatedTo` on `MyTabView` get called when I'm doing a navigation request with the scoped `RegionManager`.

**So overall** I want to inject a default view into that region on `MyTabView` right after it added. The `RegionManager` on `MyTabView` is null in the constructor, so I can't use the constructor to add the default view.

Comment: Who adds the `MyTabView`? Why can't he do the initial navigation? Are you talking about `MyTabView`'s constructor or `MyTabViewModel`'s?

Comment: A Button with a command on some other region injects the new tab. `MyTabViewModel`'s Constructor. All tabs have their own scoped region manager.